# How to create a new React project without using additional frameworks?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I would like to create a simple React app with typescript, but the [official documentation about creating a new project](https://react.dev/learn/start-a-new-react-project) guides me towards other 3rd party frameworks like Next.js and Remix. How to start a project without those?

Comment: From the page you linked: https://react.dev/learn/start-a-new-react-project#can-i-use-react-without-a-framework and https://react.dev/learn/add-react-to-an-existing-project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a project `my-app` using [create react app](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app):

```
npx create-react-app my-app --template typescript
cd my-app
```

Start the development server:

```
npm start
```

Bundle the app into static files for production:

```
npm run build
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you mean by "with no framework".

At it's core, React is just a JS library for creating reusable components, and ReactDOM is another JS library for managing HTML elements in React. You can include them by simply adding `<script>` tags to your HTML.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.production.min.js" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js" />
```

Alternatively, if you're using NPM or a similar package manager, you can install the packages:

```
npm install react react-dom
```

Both of these methods will be enough for using React, but without the JSX syntax since it isn't native JavaScript. If you want to use JSX you'll need a compiler like [Babel](https://babeljs.io/) that can transpile JSX into JavaScript. Or, since you're already using a TypeScript compiler - [configure it to transpile JSX](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/jsx.html).

If you want TypeScript to recognize React-related types, you'll have to make sure they're installed, too.

```
npm install --save-dev @types/react
```

Lastly, you'll need to run the compiler whenever you want a change in the code to take effect in the app. You can either do that manually or configure scripts for it.

In addition, while not directly related to React, you'll probably want to use a bundler to bundle your modules, a development server, test tools, and more. This all definitely *can* be done from scratch, but it's a lot of work.

That's where "mini-frameworks" come to help, providing you with a configured and ready-to-use environment to start with. The most well-known tools of this type for React are [Create React App](https://create-react-app.dev/), and [Vite](https://vitejs.dev/) - which isn't React-specific but has templates for initializing React apps, either with or without TypeScript.

Naturally, using such a tool comes with the cost of not having complete control and full flexibility over the details. It's up to you to choose what to use.

Without giving a personal opinion, it should also be noted that many consider Create React App to be outdated, and if I'm not wrong, that's why React dropped their recommendation for it. However as you noticed, they didn't put Vite or any other similar tool in it's place and only remained with a recommendation to use a fully-featured framework such as NextJS or Remix. If you don't want to use them, Vite is probably the most popular approach as of now.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Create React App](https://create-react-app.dev/) or [Vite](https://vitejs.dev/) (which is faster).

```bash
npm init vite@latest -- --template react
npm init vite@latest -- --template react-ts # to add TypeScript
```